# Jetson TX1 Qt Invalid opcode

Tags: c++, qt, arm, qml, nvidia

I have compiled (make -j4) and installed (sudo make install) Qt 5.9.1 on Jetson TX1 Board from NVIDIA with following configure command

```
./configure 
 -opensource 
 -confirm-license 
 -release
 -linuxfb
 -no-tslib
 -no-sql-sqlite
 -qt-libpng
 -qt-libjpeg
 -qt-freetype
 -qt-xkbcommon-x11
 -skip multimedia
 -skip wayland
 -skip winextras
 -skip webchannel
 -skip webengine
 -skip websockets
 -skip webkit
 -skip webview
 -skip webkit-examples
 -nomake examples
 -nomake tests
 -nomake tools
 -prefix /usr
 -opengl es2
```

Everything compiled fine and my QtQuick Project also compiled fine.
The trouble started, when i executed the program.
In release mode the program would run for half a minute and then crash without any message. In debug mode the program crashes at startup. I used Callgrind to pinpoint the crash reason and got the following messages:
[image]

Since I have compiled Qt with provided gcc/g++ compiler i don't get why an invalid opcode can be found in the libraries. 
Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer, you have tried to run that program is a pc, and do a detailed debugging. Maybe you have a task that is consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: The program runs perfectly fine on desktop and memory shouldn't be a problem, since the program crashes because of an invalid opcode due to bad complation or memory corruption. Either case it's something wrong with qt, since my program didn't even have a chance to corrupt memory :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think after tedious debugging I got to the origin of the problem.
Apparently the usage of QCharts in QML on aarch64 Systems doesn't really work, at least it produces the crashes. When removing all QCharts from my QML files the program started working, though I now got a memory leak, that might be originating from the QML Image class (even though caching is disabled), so I'm thinking about replacing it with my own renderalgorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I also got some troubles on Jetson TX2 when using Qt (OS: Ubuntu 16.04, x64). I used this tutorial:
[Install Jetson](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/11/10/qt-nvidia-jetson-tx1-device-creation-style/)

It´s working for me so perhaps you can try it with mentioned dependences.

Comment: Thanks for that link, though i knew of this tutorial. I wanted to avoid the cross compilation because i want to be able to do changes on the fly on the board and if cross compilation works, then it also should work if i compile it on the board. First thing i'll try on monday though will be to compile a basic qml application and see if it also crashes. After that i'll try to cross compile if previous attempt didn't work. So thanks for your input. (Also dependencies aren't a problem. The output of the configure command is as expected and has all features wanted)